# Difference between Attaching a file & Uploading a file to the SharePoint site

Tags: 2010, document-library, file-upload, attachments

I facing a weird issue. I am able to upload a 32 mb file to a Document Library. But I am unable to attach same file to a task. Do I need to change settings other than Central Admin?

I have set limit to 50MB in Central Admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not weird, it's by design. Attachments limit size is (if I remember correctly) also limited by the `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="size"/>` element in web.config. Check that.

Answer (score 3):

Just a side note. `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="" />` does not work for IIS 7. It has a new setting under system.webServer. See this blog for a reference: http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2009/09/24/from-iis6-maxrequestlength-to-iis7-maxallowedcontentlengthfile-specifying-maximum-file-upload-size.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that attachments are enabled on the Tasks list.